# Parse and add a class to outermost div

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

What can be the regex to parse an html and modify the html such that the outermost 'div' having our custom class?

for example: 
my input html can be like:

```
<p><div>sample text<div>this is another div</div></div></p>
```

I want a result like

```
<p><div class="myclass">sample text<div>this is another div</div></div></p>
```

Comment: Why would you want to use a Regexp for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're manipulating just a raw string that happens to contain html-like syntax, you'll probably want something like this:

```
var htmlString = '<p><div>sample text<div>this is another div</div></div></p>'

var className = 'test';
var firstDivIndex = htmlString.indexOf('<div') + 4;
var manipulatedHtml = htmlString.substring(0, firstDivIndex) + ' class="' + className + '"' + htmlString.substring(firstDivIndex);

console.log(manipulatedHtml)
```

This isn't using regex, just simple string manipulation, I'll throw together a codepen for you if you'd like as well

EDIT: Alright, here's an example with the desired functionality, open up your console to see the result - http://codepen.io/csavage1994/pen/PpRNPa

Comment: This is what I want. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome! Would you mind marking this as the accepted answer? :D